# pyspark read text file with multiline column

Tags: csv, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, etl

I have the following bad formatted txt file:

```
id;text;contact_id
1;Reason contact\
\
The client was not satisfied about the quality of the product\
\
;c_102932131
```

I'm trying to load the file using pyspark by using:

```
df = sc.read\
.option("delimiter", ";")\
.option("header", "true")\
.option("inferSchema", "true")\
.option("multiLine", "true")\
.option("wholeFile", "true")\
.csv(os.path.join(appconfig.configs[appconfig.ENV]["ROOT_DIR"], "data", "input", file_name))
```

But the column text is truncated, since the dataframe is:

```
id|text|contact_id
1|Reason contact|null
null|null|c_102932131
```

So I lose all the other lines. The goal is to read correctly the file in this way:

```
id|text|contact_id
1|Reason contact The client was satisfied not about the quality of the product|c_102932131
```

How can I do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `.wholeTextFiles` and then replace `new line (\n)` and `\` finally create df.

**`Example:`**

**`Spark-Scala:`**

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("<file_path>").
toDF().
selectExpr("""split(replace(regexp_replace(_2,"[\\\\|\n]",""),"id;text;contact_id",""),";") as new""").
withColumn("id",col("new")(0)).
withColumn("text",col("new")(1)).
withColumn("contact_id",col("new")(2)).
drop("new").
show(false)
//+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
//|id |text                                                                       |contact_id |
//+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
//|1  |Reason contactThe client was not satisfied about the quality of the product|c_102932131|
//+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

**`Pyspark:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

sc.wholeTextFiles("<file_path>").\
toDF().\
selectExpr("""split(replace(regexp_replace(_2,'[\\\\\\\\|\n]',''),"id;text;contact_id",""),";") as new""").\
withColumn("id",col("new")[0]).\
withColumn("text",col("new")[1]).\
withColumn("contact_id",col("new")[2]).\
drop("new").\
show(10,False)
#+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
#|id |text                                                                       |contact_id |
#+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
#|1  |Reason contactThe client was not satisfied about the quality of the product|c_102932131|
#+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you explain the function selectExpr as you wrote in the example? What is _2? Refers to the column? What is the last ""? Thank you

Comment: @br1, Yes,`_2` is the column name after converting to `dataframe` and `selectExpr` is used to execute set of sql expressions http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr and `"""` treat as `string` the whole expression in selectExpr.

Comment: thank your for your answer. It is actually working!

Comment: Hi, your solution works only with one line. If you have multiple lines, your solution splits everything to only one element. This is not correct. Maybe the problem is in the split function.