# Why does my PySpark regular expression not give more than the first row?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, distributed-computing

Taking inspiration from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61444594/4367851 I have been able to split my .txt file into columns in a Spark DataFrame. However, it only gives me the first game - even though the sample .txt file contains many more.

My code:

```
basefile = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("example copy 2.txt").toDF().\
    selectExpr("""split(replace(regexp_replace(_2, '\\\\n', ','), ""),",") as new""").\
    withColumn("Event", col("new")[0]).\
    withColumn("White", col("new")[2]).\
    withColumn("Black", col("new")[3]).\
    withColumn("Result", col("new")[4]).\
    withColumn("UTCDate", col("new")[5]).\
    withColumn("UTCTime", col("new")[6]).\
    withColumn("WhiteElo", col("new")[7]).\
    withColumn("BlackElo", col("new")[8]).\
    withColumn("WhiteRatingDiff", col("new")[9]).\
    withColumn("BlackRatingDiff", col("new")[10]).\
    withColumn("ECO", col("new")[11]).\
    withColumn("Opening", col("new")[12]).\
    withColumn("TimeControl", col("new")[13]).\
    withColumn("Termination", col("new")[14]).\
    drop("new")


basefile.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|               Event|          White|            Black|        Result|             UTCDate|             UTCTime|         WhiteElo|         BlackElo|     WhiteRatingDiff|     BlackRatingDiff|        ECO|             Opening|         TimeControl|         Termination|
+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[Event "Rated Cla...|[White "BFG9k"]|[Black "mamalak"]|[Result "1-0"]|[UTCDate "2012.12...|[UTCTime "23:01:03"]|[WhiteElo "1639"]|[BlackElo "1403"]|[WhiteRatingDiff ...|[BlackRatingDiff ...|[ECO "C00"]|[Opening "French ...|[TimeControl "600...|[Termination "Nor...|
+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Input file:

```
[Event "Rated Classical game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/j1dkb5dw"]
[White "BFG9k"]
[Black "mamalak"]
[Result "1-0"]
[UTCDate "2012.12.31"]
[UTCTime "23:01:03"]
[WhiteElo "1639"]
[BlackElo "1403"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "+5"]
[BlackRatingDiff "-8"]
[ECO "C00"]
[Opening "French Defense: Normal Variation"]
[TimeControl "600+8"]
[Termination "Normal"]

1. e4 e6 2. d4 b6 3. a3 Bb7 4. Nc3 Nh6 5. Bxh6 gxh6 6. Be2 Qg5 7. Bg4 h5 8. Nf3 Qg6 9. Nh4 Qg5 10. Bxh5 Qxh4 11. Qf3 Kd8 12. Qxf7 Nc6 13. Qe8# 1-0

[Event "Rated Classical game"]
.
.
.
```

Each game starts with `[Event` so I feel like it should be doable as the file has repeating structure, alas I can't get it to work.

Extra points:

1. I don't actually need the move list so if it's easier they can be deleted.
2. I only want the content of what is inside the " " for each new line once it has been converted to a Spark DataFrame.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wholeTextFiles](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles.html) reads each file into a single record. If you read only one file, the result will a RDD with only one row, containing the whole text file. The regexp logic in the question returns only one result per row and this will be the first entry in the file.

Probably the best solution would be to split the file at the os level into one file per game (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11313852/2129801)) so that Spark can read the multiple games in parallel. But if a single file is not too big, splitting the games can also be done within PySpark:

Read the file(s):

```python
basefile = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(<....>).toDF()
```

Create a list of columns and convert this list into a list of column expressions using [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html):

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = ['Event', 'White', 'Black', 'Result', 'UTCDate', 'UTCTime', 'WhiteElo', 'BlackElo', 'WhiteRatingDiff', 'BlackRatingDiff', 'ECO', 'Opening', 'TimeControl', 'Termination']
cols = [F.regexp_extract('game', rf'{col} \"(.*)\"',1).alias(col) for col in cols]
```

Extract the data:

1. split the whole file into an array of games
2. [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) this array into single records
3. delete the line breaks within each record so that the regular expression works
4. use the column expressions defined above to extract the data

```python
basefile.selectExpr("split(_2,'\\\\[Event ') as game") \
  .selectExpr("explode(game) as game") \
  .withColumn("game", F.expr("concat('Event ', replace(game, '\\\\n', ''))")) \
  .select(cols) \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Output (for an input file containing three copies of the game):

```
+---------------------+-----+-------+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+---------------+---------------+---+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
|Event                |White|Black  |Result|UTCDate   |UTCTime |WhiteElo|BlackElo|WhiteRatingDiff|BlackRatingDiff|ECO|Opening                         |TimeControl|Termination|
+---------------------+-----+-------+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+---------------+---------------+---+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
|Rated Classical game |BFG9k|mamalak|1-0   |2012.12.31|23:01:03|1639    |1403    |+5             |-8             |C00|French Defense: Normal Variation|600+8      |Normal     |
|Rated Classical game2|BFG9k|mamalak|1-0   |2012.12.31|23:01:03|1639    |1403    |+5             |-8             |C00|French Defense: Normal Variation|600+8      |Normal     |
|Rated Classical game3|BFG9k|mamalak|1-0   |2012.12.31|23:01:03|1639    |1403    |+5             |-8             |C00|French Defense: Normal Variation|600+8      |Normal     |
+---------------------+-----+-------+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+---------------+---------------+---+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. Read 411k games in 0.3 seconds.

It does cause thos error when I try to load a 912mb file on my iMac with 16gb of RAM but I assume a new question is more appropriate to keep this one on topic.

Exception in thread "stdout writer for python" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Comment: @BlueTurtle it might me a problem with the memory of the Spark driver. But it's difficult to say without more details/code